# Why the variable value is not changing in the function?

Tags: bash, makefile

In the following function `main_script`, the variable `DEFAULT_BACKUP_DIR` is not working as intended because the value `/home/user/BACKUP` is not assigned to it which I do not know why, and when I try to update it in the if statement it also does not update

Note 1: This function is inside a Makefile that I use to run a Bach script file

Note 2: The variable `DEFAULT_BACKUP_DIR` is declared for the first time in this function and used within the scope of this function only.

```
define main_script
@ $(call src_dir_check,$1)
DEFAULT_BACKUP_DIR=/home/user/BACKUP
if [ -d $2 ]
then
    echo "Backup directory -$2- do exist"
    DEFAULT_BACKUP_DIR=$2
else 
    echo "ERROR! Backup directory -$2- does not exist!"
    echo "Switched to default directory -$(DEFAULT_BACKUP_DIR)-"
fi
$(call run_script,$1,$(DEFAULT_BACKUP_DIR),$3,$4)
endef
```

this is how I call it

```
.PHONY: run
run: display
    @ $(call main_script,$(SRC_DIR),$(BACKUP_DIR),$(TIME),$(MAX))
```

and I type the following in the terminal to run the Makefile

```
make run SRC_DIR=somedir BACKUP_DIR=somedir TIME=1 MAX=5
```

thanks in advance...

Comment: What type of script are you using this in?  You tagged bash but bash doesn't use `define` at all to define any variables.

Comment: @Terrance this function is inside a Makefile that I use to run a bash file

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux?

Comment: @user68186 Ubuntu-20.04.3

Comment: I have never created my own makefile, but from your code it just doesn't look quite right.  I won't be much help because I am not seeing how you will be calling it.  However, I do recommend that you look over the Makefile Tutorial  https://makefiletutorial.com/